# Storing dictionary from excel

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to make dictionary from excel. I have written one code but it is not giving dictionary as expected. Under one policy map all data should come till than other policy map comes. You will get that from expected output.

This is the excel:
[image: Sheet1.xlsx]

This is my expected output:

```
res1= {'Nodeb_IN_New':{'policy_id':107,'default':'class-default','mplsa':['h10','h11','l12','l13','l14'],'mpls':['h1','h2','l1'],'qos':[7,5,4],'nokia':'dscp-fc-map','dscp':['ef','af41,'af11','af21','af31']},'Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN':{'policy_id':'102',default':",'mplsa':['h15','h16'],'mpls':['h1'],'qos':[7],'nokia':'dscp-fc-map','dscp':['ef','nc1']}}
```

I have written the code like this:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

book = open_workbook('test.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)

# read header values into the list    
keys = [sheet.cell(0, col_index).value for col_index in range(sheet.ncols)]

dict_list = []
for row_index in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    d = {keys[col_index]: sheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value 
         for col_index in range(sheet.ncols)}
    dict_list.append(d)

print (dict_list)
```

And getting a different output:

```
[{'policy_map': 'Nodeb_IN_New', 'policy_id': 107.0, 'default': 'class-default', 'class': 'mobility-platinum', 'mplsa': 'h10', 'mpls': 'h1', 'qos': 7.0, 'nokia': 'dscp-fc-map', 'dscp': "['ef']"}, {'policy_map': '', 'policy_id': '', 'default': '', 'class': 'mobility-gold-new', 'mplsa': 'h11', 'mpls': 'h2', 'qos': 5.0, 'nokia': 'dscp-fc-map', 'dscp': "['af41']"}, {'policy_map': '', 'policy_id': '', 'default': '', 'class': 'mobility-silver-new', 'mplsa': 'l12 l13 l14', 'mpls': 'l1', 'qos': 4.0, 'nokia': 'dscp-fc-map', 'dscp': "['af11', 'af21', 'af31']"}, {'policy_map': 'Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN', 'policy_id': 102.0, 'default': '', 'class': 'Nokia_SRAN_mobility_platinum', 'mplsa': 'h15 h16', 'mpls': 'h1', 'qos': 7.0, 'nokia': 'dscp-fc-map', 'dscp': "['ef', 'nc1']"}]
```

Please suggest a better code to get output as required.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
result = {}
for row_index in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    result[sheet.cell(row_index, 0).value] = {keys[col_index]: sheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value 
                                              for col_index in range(1,sheet.ncols)}

print (result)
```

Comment: getting output like this:    {'Nodeb_IN_New': {'policy_id': 107.0, 'default': 'class-default', 'class': 'mobility-platinum', 'mplsa': 'h10', 'mpls': 'h1', 'qos': 7.0, 'nokia': 'dscp-fc-map', 'dscp': "['ef']"}, '': {'policy_id': '', 'default': '', 'class': 'mobility-silver-new', 'mplsa': 'l12 l13 l14', 'mpls': 'l1', 'qos': 4.0, 'nokia': 'dscp-fc-map', 'dscp': "['af11', 'af21', 'af31']"}, 'Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN': {'policy_id': 102.0, 'default': '', 'class': 'Nokia_SRAN_mobility_platinum', 'mplsa': 'h15 h16', 'mpls': 'h1', 'qos': 7.0, 'nokia': 'dscp-fc-map', 'dscp': "['ef', 'nc1']"}}  lil diff